# Error if I press 'Back' after Google contact import API

Tags: api, import, contacts, back-button

After importing contacts using Google API, it's successful.  **When I press the back button**, I get this scary message.  I don't want users to be able to see this.  Can it be fixed?

```
An error occurred
An error occurred during execution; please try again later.
Additional information:
Google_AuthException
File:
/var/www/zanzibar/vendor/googleApi/auth/Google_OAuth2.php:114
Message:
Error fetching OAuth2 access token, message: 'invalid_grant'
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/zanzibar/vendor/googleApi/Google_Client.php(131): Google_OAuth2-        >authenticate(Array, NULL)
#1 /var/www/zanzibar/library/Modules/Contacts/views/contacts/import/google.phtml(39): Google_Client->authenticate()
#2 /var/www/zanzibar/vendor/Zend/View/Renderer/PhpRenderer.php(507): include('/var/www/zanzib...')
#3 /var/www/zanzibar/vendor/Zend/View/View.php(205): Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer->render(Object(Zend\View\Model\ViewModel))
#4 /var/www/zanzibar/vendor/Zend/View/View.php(233): Zend\View\View->render(Object(Zend\View\Model\ViewModel))
#5 /var/www/zanzibar/vendor/Zend/View/View.php(198): Zend\View\View->renderChildren(Object(Zend\View\Model\ViewModel))
#6 /var/www/zanzibar/vendor/Zend/Mvc/View/Http/DefaultRenderingStrategy.php(102): Zend\View\View->render(Object(Zend\View\Model\ViewModel))
#7 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\View\Http\DefaultRenderingStrategy->render(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#8 /var/www/zanzibar/vendor/Zend/EventManager/EventManager.php(468): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#9 /var/www/zanzibar/vendor/Zend/EventManager/EventManager.php(207): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners('render', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Array)
#10 /var/www/zanzibar/vendor/Zend/Mvc/Application.php(347): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->trigger('render', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#11 /var/www/zanzibar/vendor/Zend/Mvc/Application.php(322): Zend\Mvc\Application->completeRequest(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#12 /var/www/zanzibar/public/index.php(35): Zend\Mvc\Application->run()
#13 {main}
```